# Why is the body height=0 on a newly created Jhipster project?

Tags: java, html, angularjs, jhipster

I just created my first jhipster application and followed the instructions on how to set up my IDE (eclipse).

After that, I ran the gradle bootRun task (in eclipse), and everything went fine.

When I visited the localhost address, the page was blank. Investigating the issue in firefox (f12), it showed that the body had a height of 0.

After trying to manually stretch the html body by setting its height manually to 100vt in the index.html file, another investigation via f12 showed, that the new settings was applied (the height was 100vt now), but the page was still blank.

**What could be the issue?** I already confirmed, that all needed files exist, so it cannot be a *file not found* issue

Interestingly, the page's name is displayed in the tab. As the name is defined in the index.html's header, the file must be correctly deployed, but there must be some kind of problem in the generated part.

**EDIT**

running `yarn run webpack:build`

```
yarn run v0.23.2
$ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:vendor && yarn run webpack:build:dev
yarn run v0.23.2
$ rimraf build/{aot,www}
The command "rimraf" is either spelled incorrectly or could not be found
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**EDIT 2**

As someone mentioned in a comment, I may have to run `yarn install`, but this gives me the following error, which I do not understand at all...

```
error C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\generator-jhipster: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c tabtab install --name jhipster --auto
Directory: C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\generator-jhipster
Output:
Fri, 30 Jun 2017 14:40:09 GMT tabtab:installer Installing completion script to fish directory
fs.js:641
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\scripts\C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.sh'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
    at Complete.script (C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\src\complete.js:373:14)
    at Installer.writeTo (C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\src\installer.js:91:34)
    at Installer.handle (C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\src\installer.js:80:21)
    at Commands.install (C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\src\commands\index.js:75:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\src\cli.js:33:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: `C:\CUBE\workspace\cube\node_modules\tabtab\scripts\C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.sh` is not a valid directory. Something is messed up at your configuration. That's why `yarn install` is not working.

Comment: @Nico I can imagine, but I did not input this path anywhere, thats the problem... The path is generated somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

when generating the app with the `git bash`, there seems to be a faulty generation schedule on windows.

I re-generated the app with the `windows cmd` and everything worked as expected...

Answer (score 1):

Did you choose Angular2?

In that case, you need to compile the front part.
Use:

- `yarn run webpack:build`
- or directly with: `yarn start`

All instructions should be mentionned in your README.md

Comment: run `yarn install`, it's obvious that you are missing some dependencies in `node_modules` folder

Comment: @GaelMariziou I added an edit with the output of yarn install

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the generation missed something.

When I started using JHipster I has similar problems.

I solved them by following the installation instructions (again). At the first try I got problems, then I re-installed all those components and then I re-generated my app.

The second time I had no problems and all went good!

In my opinion some errors come out during generation process, that's why your page comes blank. Try to re-install, or simply update, your tools and plugins and then re-generate your project.

Follow this [link](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/) for further informations.

Comment: Well, I already re-generated the app twice, on different machines. Same error on both...